# How to scan a QueryRow to existing map[string]interface{} in Go

Tags: go

How to scan a QueryRow to existing map[string]interface{} in Go? I would like to use the below code to get bother `data` and `new_data`, but
no matter how to change, I always get error of `undefined:new_data`, thanks so much for any advice.

```golang
func init() {
    lmhttp.ResponseHook["/login"] = Login()
}

func Login() func(c *lmhttp.Context, code int, data interface{}) (int, interface{}) {
    return func(c *lmhttp.Context, code int, data interface{}) (int, interface{}) {
        method := c.Request.Method
        var req loginReq
        if method == "POST" {
            var des string
            if err := db.QueryRow("SELECT des FROM user WHERE email=?",
                req.Email).Scan(&des); err != nil {
                if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
                    fmt.Errorf("Failed！", req.Email)
                }
                fmt.Errorf("Failed！", req.Email)

            }
            var tmp = make(map[string]interface{})
            tmp["des"] = des

            fmt.Print("this is des", des)

            tmp1, err := json.Marshal(tmp)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Failed", err)
            }

            var new_data = make(map[string]interface{})
            err = json.Unmarshal(tmp1, &new_data)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            fmt.Print("this is new_data", new_data)
        }
        return code, map[string]interface{}{"data": data, "new_data": new_data}
    }
}
```

Comment: The error means that you are referencing an undeclared name. Go is block scoped. `var new_data ...` inside the `if` block will NOT be accessible outside of it. The error has *nothing* to do with QueryRow.

Comment: Move the declaration of new_data before the if statement.

Comment: The code does not seem to match the title. And I honestly fail to understand those JSON munging.

Comment: "scan a QueryRow to existing map[string]interface{} in Go": This is not possible, as Go is strongly typed and therefore needs to know into which concrete type a value that is fetched from a query result should be put.

Comment: @Peter Hi Peter, You saved my day!! Thank you so much!!Your suggestion is feasible.How did you see the problem at a glance?I admire you so much.Can you share the books or tutorials you read?

Comment: @Peter Please answer this question intead of comment, I'm going to set yours as the best answer