# How to get value of interface {} in Go? (interface conversion: interface {} is Resp, not map[string]interface {})

Tags: go

According to this question and the Go code [scan a QueryRow to existing map[string]interface{} in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75412279/how-to-scan-a-queryrow-to-existing-mapstringinterface-in-go), I am trying to get key and value of `data["id"]`

```golang
func Login() func(c *lmhttp.Context, code int, data interface{}) (int, interface{}) {
    return func(c *lmhttp.Context, code int, data interface{}) (int, interface{}) {
    map_data := data.(map[string]interface{})
    fmt.Print(map_data, map_data["id"])
  }
}
```

but I always got error as below,thanks so much for any advice.

```golang
interface conversion: interface {} is LoginResp, not map[string]interface {}
```

And I also paste my `Response` code as below:

```golang
func (c *Context) Response(data interface{}) {
    c.result(http.StatusOK, data)
}
```

Comment: @mkopriva hi thanks so much for your comment, code of LoginResp works well, there is no problem, I just want to get value from `data`, I don't know how to get it

Comment: @mkopriva hi, I also updated my `Response` code in question, and `LoginResp ` is just a struct that defines some fields

Comment: @mkopriva Finally, I get value by the below code, use Marshal to get JSON data, then map and Unmarshal it, thanks all the same for reading my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I get value by the below code, use `Marshal` to get `JSON` data, then `map` and `Unmarshal` it,

```golang
json_str, jsonErr := json.Marshal(data)
if json_str != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%v", jsonErr)
}
m := make(map[string]interface{})
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(json_str), &m)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println("This is ID", m["id"])
}
```